# Why does map::find need my parameter to not be const?

Tags: c++, stl

```
std::map<Item*, item_quantity_t> _items;

bool Inventory::hasItem(Item const& item) {

    return (_items.find(&item) != _items.end() );

};
```

This code won't work, but changing the input type of "hasItem" to  `Item & item` will work...
can someone explain why to me? I've seen that std::find takes a const reference, so passing it a const object should be ok, at least it's what I understand

Comment: std::map<const Item*, item_quantity_t> _items; might be one solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've defined that the key type for your map is a pointer to a non-const Item, `Item*`. The `find` method expects a (const reference to a) value of the key type, so it requires a pointer to non-const.

When you expand the templates, the parameter type of `find` is `Item* const&`.

You can either change your `hasItem` to take a non-const reference `Item&`, or you can change your key type to be a pointer to a const Item `Item const*`.

Answer (score 2):

> std::find takes a const reference

This is true, but all it means is that the method won't modify the `Item *`. In order to pass in a `const Item *` (which is what `&item` is), you'd need a guarantee that the method won't modify the underlying `Item`. That guarantee does actually exist, but C++ can't tell that. So you'd have to write:

```
_items.find(const_cast<Item *>(&item))
```

to inform C++ that you know this is safe.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've defined the map to contain non-const pointers, that's the type you'll need to call `find`, and you can't get one of those from a const reference. You could change the key type to a const pointer:

```
std::map<Item const *, item_quantity_t> _items;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would work if your map was over a pointers to const items:

```
std::map<const Item*, item_quantity_t> _items;
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::map<Key, Value>::find()` doesn't care about the argument passed being `const`. However, you seem to care deeply about you key type being a non-`const` pointer to `Item` which you won't get from taking the address of a `Item const&`. That said, I doubt that you really want to use pointers as the key to you map.